# Перегрузка операторов в С++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Есть три класса `Matrix` - матрица, `VectorRow` - вектор строка и `VectorColumn` - вектор столбец. Если мы перемножим объекты `vectorRow *= vectorColumn`, то на выходе по законам природы у нас будет матрица. Можно ли перегрузить оператор *=, чтобы реализовать то что я описал? Т.е. что-то вроде `Matrix operator*=(const VectorColumn& v1, const VectorRow& v2)`?

Comment: Может вам нужен `*`, а не `*=`? `*=` не может изменить тип левого операнда (да и вообще, нельзя изменить тип уже существующей переменной).

Comment: Нельзя, потому что оператор *= (для встроенных типов)  меняет значение левого аргумента, не меняя его тип, а у вас, тип аргумента не совпадает с типом результата. Т.е. определить можно, и это даже будет компилироваться, но будет обманывать ожидания пользователей. Это как для вычитания перегрузить оператор +.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, видимо действительно остается только `*`.

Comment: Можно: `Matrix operator*=(VectorColumn const & v)`, хотя использование возвращаемого значения оператора присваивания - сомнительная практика.

Comment: @user7860670, в этом случае будет умножение матрицы на вектор-столбец, а не вектор-строка на вектор-столбец.

Comment: user7860670, и кстати говоря, при умножении матрицы на вектор-столбец в результате имеем вектор столбец, т.е. то что вы предлагаете - корректно, только в том случае, если размерность возвращаемой матрицы будет nx1.

Comment: Нет, там идет речь об умножении одного вектора на другой, а матрица будет результатом операции

Comment: @user7860670, матрицу вижу, вектор-столбец тоже, вектор строку не вижу

Comment: Это подразумевается метод класса вектор, так что оба аргумента - вектора.

Comment: @user7860670, вектро-столбец и вектор-строка это разные классы

Comment: Ну тогда `VectorColumn` - `this`, а `VectorRow` - аргумент

Comment: @user7860670, кстати да, спасибо большое!

Comment: Вообще то лучшая кандидатура для реализации матричного класса, это std::valarray а не вектор....

Answer (score 1):

Вы путаете два случая - `operator*` (умножение, которое даёт другой объект, чем аргументы) и `operator*=` (умножение, которое модифицирует аргументы). Если у вас тип результата другой, чем тип аргументов, `*=` уже не подходит.

Вы можете, безусловно, сделать

```
Matrix operator*(const VectorColumn& v1, const VectorRow& v2)
```

но это должен быть не метод класса, а отдельная функция. Вот в ней и будет умножение. Создайте в ней локальный объект Matrix, заполните и верните. Следует проследить, чтобы на этом возврате Matrix компилятор правильно отработал [Return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization).

PS: рекомендую уточнить заголовок вопроса, сейчас он слишком невнятный.

Comment: Я ничего не путаю, вопрос был именно про `*=`. Спасибо за ответ.